# Simulating a network video transfer using my home devices

Tags: networking

Working on my thesis I need to create a simulation for video transmission in a normal WLAN to detect how much the quality is reduced depending on the number of devices or quality of originating transmission.

I was using NS-3 for this when someone proposed to me to use my home devices (I have a number of computers, tablets, E-readers, video game consoles etc).

It seemed to me like a good idea since I have a fast enough WiFi I can just use my Mac as the hotspot and connect all devices through it then sniff the packets with wireshark and limit the speed of the transfer using "Network Link Conditioner" my question is, would limiting the speed of transfer with the network link conditioner affect the devices using my computer as a hotspot? or does it only affect my personal computer and I need to figure another way of limiting the speed to successfully simulate what I need?

Comment: AFAIK, network link conditioner throttles your interface.  Have you tried running a simple test like loading a web page from a device connected to your hotspot and monitoring your speeds?

Comment: I have and although the speed decrements I never get any "dropped packets" in wireshark so I thought I was doing something wrong or aren't I? I filter by "tcp.analysis.lost_segment" and get 470 packets but I'm unsure whether those were actually "dropped" and also if there are other connections (like UDP) how can I get those

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are after, but seeing you mentioned *limiting bandwidth on your Mac*, this may be in use:

Basically, you'll need a PC that can run FreeBSD and two network interfaces (e.g. a built in NIC plus one other card). You then setup the box to bridge those two cards.

Check out this tutorial to see how [Network Bandwidth Latency and Delay Simulation Tutorial](http://www.technogumbo.com/tutorials/Network-Bandwidth-Latency-and-Delay-Simulation-Tutorial/Network-Bandwidth-Latency-and-Delay-Simulation-Tutorial.php)

Once setup you can then control the parameters of that bridge using the ipfw command in FreeBSD, allowing you to change bit rates, latency and simulate packet loss.

With this box in between your video sources (the internet?) and with a wifi router on the other side to connect your devices to, you'd be able to simulate a variety of conditions.

[Note: credit for digging this out this link needs to go to a colleague of mine, but I used this on a project once he'd set it up and it was very powerful]